# How can I add or remove class using querySelectorAll() in react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to add or remove an active class if I click any list item but the code is not working.
**Here is my function**

```
    const list = document.querySelectorAll('.m-list') as NodeListOf<Element>

    function activeLink(this: any) {
        list.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove('active'))
        // list.forEach((item) => item.classList.add('active'))
        this.classList.add('active')
    }
    list.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', activeLink))
```

**Full code with HTML**

```
export default function MobileNavigation() {
    const list = document.querySelectorAll('.m-list') as NodeListOf<Element>

    function activeLink(this: any) {
        list.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove('active'))
        // list.forEach((item) => item.classList.add('active'))
        this.classList.add('active')
    }
    list.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', activeLink))



    return <div className='mobile-navigation'>
        <ul>
            <li className='m-list active'>
                <a href="#">
                    <span className='m-icon'><i className="fa-solid fa-house"></i></span>
                    <span className='m-text'>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li className='m-list'>
                <a href="#">
                    <span className='m-icon'><i className="fa-solid fa-shop"></i></span>
                    <span className='m-text'>Shop</span></a>
            </li>
            <li className='m-list'>
                <a href="#"><span className='m-icon'><i className="fa-solid fa-store"></i></span>
                    <span className='m-text'>Vendors</span></a>
            </li>
            <li className='m-list'>
                <a href="#"><span className='m-icon'><i className="fa-solid fa-address-card"></i></span>
                    <span className='m-text'>About us</span></a>
            </li>
            <li className='m-list'>
                <a href="#"><span className='m-icon'><i className="fa-solid fa-headset"></i></span>
                    <span className='m-text'>Contact Us</span></a>
            </li>
            <div className="indicator"></div>
        </ul>
    </div>;
}
```

Comment: `the code is not working` is not a problem statement - of course it isn't working, that's why you asked a question ... what is happening instead? have you checked the developer tools console for errors, for example

Comment: try replacing `this: any` with `e: any` ... since `this` can not be used like this

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with `e:any` but it's not working. The new class is not adding to the element

Comment: add some console logging to debug the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.m-list') as NodeListOf<Element>

 function activeLink(e:any) {
        list.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove('active'))
        // list.forEach((item) => item.classList.add('active'))
        e.classList.add('active')
    }
 list.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', (e)=>activeLink(item)))
```

Just replace this with your code ... it will start working now .
I hope this helped you solve your issue :)

Comment: Please upvote the solution if you find it helpful .
It will help other users with similar problems get their solution fast and easy .
Thanks !